# Vote counting issue in the Ethereum Association DAO example?

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, dao

My question is about the Ethereum DAO Association example found [here](https://www.ethereum.org/dao).

My question is on this bit of code:

```
struct Proposal {
    address recipient;
    uint amount;
    string description;
    uint votingDeadline;
    bool executed;
    bool proposalPassed;
    uint numberOfVotes;
    bytes32 proposalHash;
    Vote[] votes;
    mapping (address => bool) voted;
}
/*....*/

function vote(uint proposalNumber, bool supportsProposal)
    onlyShareholders
    returns (uint voteID)
{
    Proposal p = proposals[proposalNumber];
    if (p.voted[msg.sender] == true) throw;

    voteID = p.votes.length++;
    p.votes[voteID] = Vote({inSupport: supportsProposal, voter: msg.sender});
    p.voted[msg.sender] = true;
    p.numberOfVotes = voteID +1;
    Voted(proposalNumber,  supportsProposal, msg.sender);
}

function executeProposal(uint proposalNumber, bytes transactionBytecode) returns (int result) {
    Proposal p = proposals[proposalNumber];
    /* Check if the proposal can be executed */
    if (now < p.votingDeadline  /* has the voting deadline arrived? */
        ||  p.executed        /* has it been already executed? */
        ||  p.proposalHash != sha3(p.recipient, p.amount, transactionBytecode)) /* Does the transaction code match the proposal? */
        throw;

    /* tally the votes */
    uint quorum = 0;
    uint yea = 0;
    uint nay = 0;

    for (uint i = 0; i <  p.votes.length; ++i) {
        Vote v = p.votes[i];
        uint voteWeight = sharesTokenAddress.balanceOf(v.voter);
        quorum += voteWeight;
        if (v.inSupport) {
            yea += voteWeight;
        } else {
            nay += voteWeight;
        }
    }

    /* execute result */
    if (quorum <= minimumQuorum) {
        /* Not enough significant voters */
        throw;
    } else if (yea > nay ) {
        /* has quorum and was approved */
        p.executed = true;
        if (!p.recipient.call.value(p.amount * 1 ether)(transactionBytecode)) {
            throw;
        }
        p.proposalPassed = true;
    } else {
        p.proposalPassed = false;
    }
    // Fire Events
    ProposalTallied(proposalNumber, result, quorum, p.proposalPassed);
}
```

Specifically,

If we add new votes doing `voteID = p.votes.length++; p.votes[voteID] = /*...*/` and then count them doing `(uint i = 0; i <  p.votes.length; ++i)` isn't there an index problem?

Here is the reasoning:

Initially the votes array is 0 hence p.votes.length = 0  and p.votes.length++ = 1 and then we increase from there. However, the loop starts counting from 0.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like with many other programming language the ++ operator is very special here

```
voteID = p.votes.length++; 
//Translates to 
voteID = p.votes.length=p.votes.length+1;

//And using operator precedence when = is involved it further Translates
// to  the following sequence of operations

voteID = p.votes.length;
p.votes.length=p.votes.length+1; // one element got added at 0th index,so the lengh is 1
```

Would it make sense ?